# What is sin i in this graph and why is it there?

Tags: exoplanet, data-analysis

[image]

This is some data presented in a lecture on exoplanets that depicts the distribution of the sizes of super-Earths in comparison to the mass of Jupiter.
 I would like to know what the argument of the sine function i.e. 'i' implies and why it was multiplied by the mass of Jupiter.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you discover an exoplanet via the Doppler (radial velocity) method, then the amplitude of the radial velocity variations depends on the *inclination*, $i,$ of the exoplanet's orbital axis with respect to your line of sight. Conventionally, $i=90^{\circ}$ corresponds to viewing an orbit "edge-on", which maximises the velocity variations, while a face-on orbit with $i=0$ would not be detectable.

[image]
[source](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-inclination-angle-i-is-defined-as-the-angle-between-the-plane-of-the-exoplane-ts_fig1_228392024)

This means that you cannot directly estimate the exoplanet mass from your radial velocity data, only $M \sin i$, as plotted on your histogram. $M \sin i$ is a *lower limit* to the mass.

The $M_{\rm Jup}$ is there to indicate that the axis is labelled in units of Jupiter masses.

Comment: Why do you say that Msini is a lower limit to the mass? Why not the upper, because there could be other planets contributing to this Doppler effect?

Comment: Wouldn't a face-on viewing mean that I = 90°, as the plane of the orbit would be making a 90° angle with the line of sight?

Comment: $M\sin i$ is a lower limit to $M$ because $\sin i \leq 1$. A face-on orbit has $i=0$; that is how $i$ is defined - the angle between the orbital axis and the line of sight.